# What is the original purpose of Django apps? What are the use cases of Django apps?

Tags: django

I'm building a website that'll use a Bootstrap template similar to the image shown below. I intend to add an authentication and authorization functionality using OAuth 2. The main menu will consist of:

- Homepage link
- Statistics app link
- NLP app link
- Computer vision app link
- Contacts page link
- Login button

Without using Django, the homepage would just be `index.html`, the Statistics app would be a `statistics.html` page which interacts with the backend to show some plots, the NLP app would be an `nlp.html` page which interacts with the backend to display some NLP processed text and so on.

When using Django, how am I supposed to structure it? Should I create a separate NLP Django app, and a separate Statistics Django app and a separate Homepage Django app? I'm already surprised that I had to create an app just to be able to have a homepage, and then had to add `path('', include('homepage.urls')),` to `urlpatterns` to redirect `/` to the homepage app.
If I use the Bootstrap template for the homepage app, then how would I share the JS files, the CSS files and other boilerplate files of the template with the other apps of my website? Once the user logs in, would the session of the homepage app be valid for the other apps too?

Do I even need to create separate apps for NLP, Statistics, computer vision etc? What exactly is the purpose of Django apps, and could you mention a few use cases of Django apps and how boilerplate template files and scripts were shared among apps? Any best-practices related to app building?

[image]

Comment: Apps are typically used to make *reusable* components. So compnents you can plug into another Django project for example.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: If it's meant to be reusable, then wouldn't each app need to have its own copy of the static files and scripts of the Bootstrap template? So that'd lead to data redundancy? Also, what's a use case for this reusability? For the example I gave, would the NLP app be an example of something that's reusable? Then shouldn't the header menu be a separate app?